# Should ViewModel in MVVM only have code for request to the helpers?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I've been reading Dependency Injection book by Mark Seemann and thoughts are all messed up once again. The point of DI is to make sure that every single class would only know about the task it handles. So would it be wise, for a ViewModel only to make requests to other classes that would handle all the work, and ViewModel would be just for binding everything to the View?

Comment: Without concrete example the question is either too broad or imho-cased.

Comment: [Counterpoint](https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/castlecrashers/images/9/9a/Troll-face.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151002165505): The point of DI is to make sure that every single class requires a tangle of wrappers that have to be written and provided to the constructor. Rather like if your local sandwich shop improved their ordering procedure so it more closely resembled applying to the NIH for a research grant.

Comment: @TomasŽemgulys More like, don't hit a tack with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well I believe that I would get a better understanding of DI by trying to implement instead of just reading even if it is kind of unnecessary

Comment: @TomasŽemgulys a) That's absolutely true. b) Not everything is a tack. Sledgehammers have their place.

Comment: Anyhow: The viewmodel's primary role is business logic, and exposing properties for views to bind to. Those properties may often include child viewmodels or observable collections of child viewmodels. For stuff like data access, it should be calling other classes. You can have the VM create those other classes directly (or use singletons etc.), or you can foster unit testing and reusability by hiding those other classes behind interfaces and using DI to provide implementations. The latter involves overhead in coding and maintenance, which may pay for itself.

Comment: As with any design pattern, the devil is in the details. Show us an implementation and we'll tell you if you're following the pattern over a cliff or  not. If you're injecting implementations of string comparison and collection enumeration, you've gone too far.

Comment: I am very thankful for your answers @EdPlunkett. I am not that much afraid of the dependency injections structure since I have a book by my side, and a senior developer shown me some code so I hope I get the idea. However I was thinking wouldn't I break the purpose of MVVM by simply hiding all the work that is being done by other classes and just simply binding to a VM. I am still juniorish so there might be flaws in my thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of the ViewModel is to adapt the Model to work with the View.

But there is some missing part in this definition - your business logic. Of course you can put it in your ViewModel, but following [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles in most cases it is a good idea to use some sort of services to get things done and DI is the right way to do this.

Although this approach might not be proper for all cases.

Comment: So basically VM contains all the business model. Therefore, it should be perfectly fine if i encapsulate that logic?

Comment: Your ViewModel should depend on interfaces that provide business logic for your app and you should use DI container to resolve them. MVVM pattern is in fact more like View-ViewModel-BusinessLogic-Model.